# Format a Date, allowing null

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to print a `Date`, just the way [`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29) does it.

`format` throws a `NullPointerException` when passing `null`, so I've been wondering if there is a different approach that would return `null` (or `"null"`) instead?

Something I'd call instead of

```
Date d = null;
System.out.println(d==null ? null : DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(d));
```

Comment: How about extending `DateFormat` class - but thats probably more complex than plain null check which you are already doing.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with d==null ? null : DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(d))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could just wrap the call inside a utility method :

```
public class DateUtils {
    public static String formatDateTime(Date dateOrNull) {
        return (dateOrNull == null ? null : DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(dateOrNull));
    }
}
```

private constructor and javadoc omitted for brevity.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was planning to do. Just wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem with your existing code?

`null` is kind of a special case, and you've decided that you want one particular behaviour in this case (returning `"null"`) instead of another particular behaviour (throwing an NPE).  It's arguably cleaner to express this via switching at the top level rather than burying this logic within the formatting method.

It might be a little cleaner to use a full if-else rather than a tertiary operator, though, to make it clearer that there are two distinct branches (normal, and special-cased `null`):

```
if (d == null) {
    return "null"; // or whatever special case
}
else {
    return DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(d);
}
```

The return value in the null case should be made clear in your method's javadocs, too.

Comment: There's not really a problem with my existing code. The thing is, that I am using this several times to log some dates, and if I forget it once, then my application might crash some day just because it could not log `null`. So if there was some standard way, I'd love to use that.

Comment: "forget it once"?  I was under the impression that this was already part of a utility function.  If not, that's your solution, as per JB Nizet's answer :)