# Error thrown while using datamapper to map date in Mule

Tags: mule, datamapper, mule-studio, mule-component

Below is the portion of the mapping in data mapper

dateTimeFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
output.Date_of_Rate_Float__c = (isnull(input.Date_of_Rate_Float) ? null : dateTimeFormatter.format(input.Date_of_Rate_Float));
output.Loan_Create_Date__c = (isnull(input.loan_create_date) ? null : dateTimeFormatter.format(input.loan_create_date));
output.Estimated_Closing_Date__c = (isnull(input.estimated_closing_date) ? null : dateTimeFormatter.format(input.estimated_closing_date));

this throws the below exception

```
1. DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion. (org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException)
  org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter:468 (null)

Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion.
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.toDate(DateTimeConverter.java:468)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.convertToType(DateTimeConverter.java:343)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.AbstractConverter.convert(AbstractConverter.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.convert(ConvertUtilsBean.java:544)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.converter.ScalarValueConversion.convert(ScalarValueConversion.java:126)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.DataRecordContext.put(DataRecordContext.java:87)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.DataRecordContext.put(DataRecordContext.java:24)
    at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.optimizeSetAccessor(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:308)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledAccExpression.setValue(CompiledAccExpression.java:54)
    at org.mvel2.ast.DeepAssignmentNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(DeepAssignmentNode.java:92)
    at org.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:85)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:113)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:942)
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:50)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.DataMapperExpressionLanguage.evaluate(DataMapperExpressionLanguage.java:106)
    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform.transform(MelRecordTransform.java:56)
    at org.jetel.component.Reformat.execute(Reformat.java:273)
    at org.jetel.graph.Node.run(Node.java:465)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

********************************************************************************
```

I'am unable to find as what is causing this exception, I would like to seek help in resolving this issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a null value is being passed to the `format` method.  To see how you can make it "null safe" you can look at the example at [Format a Date, allowing null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432128/format-a-date-allowing-null)

Comment: I have checked the data being sent to Data Mapper and it doesnt have any null values and also if i remove the Date Formatter  in the Data Mapper it doesn't throw error. Do you know as why the  Date Formatter causes error.